# Where does Sass look for imports?

Tags: sass

Let's say I've got a file at `./styles/main.scss` containing this:

```
@import 'foo'
```

And I render it with Sass, also setting `./bower_components` as a load path.

As far as Sass knows, the file could be located at `./styles/foo.scss`, or `./styles/_foo.scss`, or even `./bower_components/foo.scss`.

Presumably it builds a list of these (and other?) 'potential' paths, then goes through them in order until it finds one that exists. What is the complete list of potential paths, in the correct order? And does the logic change if you explicity define the extension (`@import 'foo.scss'`)?

Answer (score 1):

> Sass looks for other Sass files in the **current directory**, and the Sass file directory under Rack, Rails, or Merb. Additional search directories may be specified using the :load_paths option, or the --load-path option on the command line.

[Sass reference - @import](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)

Relative paths can of course also be provided, relative from the current directory.